# React SEO subpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in react and I try do my first app but I have problems with SEO on subpages 
http://programy-online.com/program/Tuhy/3
My content in javascript isnt visable for google how I can fix that ?

Comment: you mus do a code universal/isomorphic try to search this concepts in githup and see examples done https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example

Comment: Ohh thx I didint know that :)

Comment: Perhaps you should go for static site generators for React such as Gatsby.js